# Change the Style Font size ect... in an String[] and Object[][] in Codename one

Tags: java, codenameone

I have a table in my codename one Porject and i want the change the header font & size and backgound color border margin ect ....

```
    String[] header = new String[]{"name", "Image", "Description", "label", "quantity", "rating", "rate"};
    Object[][] rows = new Object[articles.size()][];
    for (int iter = 0;iter < rows.length;iter++) {
        rows[iter] = new Object[]{
            articles.get(iter).getName(),
            articles.get(iter).getId_article(),
            articles.get(iter).getDescription(),
            articles.get(iter).getLabel(),
            articles.get(iter).getQuantity(),
            articles.get(iter).getRating(),
            articles.get(iter).getId_article()
        };
    }

    TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(header, rows);
            add(table);
```

Comment: @camickr This is a Codename One question not a Swing question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't and shouldn't style the strings. The headers already have a different style UUID of `TableHeader` which you can style as opposed to `TableCell`. This allows you to separate the design styling and the data.

You can see all of the UIIDs in the Component Inspector tool in the simulator and style the elements appropriately.

Notice that if you overrode that `createCell()` method and didn't invoke super for header calls (whose row is -1) this might not be the case. In that case you should just use `setUIID()` to set the style of the header explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

i have used the createCell() method to change the header as for the rows i haven's found a way to change them the way i intended sadly